# Tkinter/Python hanging on user response if response is the last option in a while or if loop

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

The following code works for requesting input from a user through the Tkinter GUI and turning that input into a usable variable in the main script.  However, any value that I put as the last in a list in the if statement (here "4") will hang and crash the program upon enter.  This was also the case for "n" in a yes/no scenario.  It also happens if I replace the if statement with a while not in [values] - the final value will crash the program.  Is this just a quirk of Tkinter or is there something that I am missing?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

# get choice back from user
    global result 
    badinput = True
    while badinput == True: 
        boxwidth = 1
        result = getinput(boxwidth).strip().lower()
        if result in ['1', '2', '3', '4']:
            badinput = False
            # iterate through play options
            if result == '1':
              # Do Something
            elif result =='2':
              # Do Something
            elif result =='3':
              # Do Something
            else:
              # Do Something

def getinput(boxwidth):

    # declaring string variable for storing user input
    answer_var = tk.StringVar()

    # defining a function that will 
    # get the answer and set it
    def user_response(event):
        answer_var.set(answer_entry.get())
        return

    answer_entry = tk.Entry(root, width = boxwidth, borderwidth = 5)

    # making it so that enter calls function
    answer_entry.bind('<Return>', user_response)

    # placing the entry 
    answer_entry.pack()
    answer_entry.focus()

    answer_entry.wait_variable(answer_var)
    answer_entry.destroy()
    return answer_var.get()
```

Comment: `while badinput == True` is a completely unworkable approach in a GUI.  If the user-entered data was bad, it will remain bad *forever*, because there's no possibility of the user input changing while your loop continues running - you have to exit back to the mainloop for anything in the GUI to actually change state.

Comment: How would I use trace in getinput() to validate the entry there and avoid using while or if in main()?

Comment: Really, for four choices in a GUI the right approach is a set of four Radiobuttons (or possibly something like an OptionMenu) - that way, there's no possibility of an invalid user input.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is following this question, I did end up solving my problem with a simple if statement within the callback.  I can feed a dynamic "choicelist" of acceptable responses into the callback upon user return.  If the answer is validated, the gate_var triggers the wait function and sends the program and user response back into the program.

'''
def getinput(boxwidth, choicelist):
# declaring string variable for storing user input
answer_var = tk.StringVar()
gate_var = tk.StringVar()
dumplist = []

```
# defining a function that will 
# get the answer and set it
def user_response(event):
    answer_var.set(answer_entry.get())

    if choicelist == None: 
        clearscreen(dumplist)
        gate_var.set(answer_entry.get())
        return
    
    if answer_var.get() in choicelist: 
        # passes a validated entry on to gate variable
        clearscreen(dumplist)
        gate_var.set(answer_entry.get())
    else:
        # return to entry function and waits if invalid entry
        clearscreen(dumplist)
        ErrorLabel = tk.Label(root, text = "That is not a valid response.")
        ErrorLabel.pack()
        ErrorLabel.config(font = ('verdana', 18), bg ='#BE9CCA')
        dumplist.append(ErrorLabel)  
    return

global topentry
if topentry == True:
    answer_entry = tk.Entry(top, width = boxwidth, borderwidth = 5)
else:
    answer_entry = tk.Entry(root, width = boxwidth, borderwidth = 5)

# making it so that enter calls function
answer_entry.bind('<Return>', user_response)

# placing the entry 
answer_entry.pack()
answer_entry.focus()

answer_entry.wait_variable(gate_var)
answer_entry.destroy()
return answer_var.get()
```

'''